# JMSListener annotation is not working along with REST service

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-jms

I am using "*Spring Boot - 2.1.5.RELEASE*" and "*Spring framework - 5.1.7.RELEASE*".
JMS listener annotation is not picking a message from a MQ queue. No error logs are rolling in my IntelliJ IDEA as well.
About my project - I am exposing a REST service which sends and receives a message from MQ (used JMSTemplate annotation). Till now it was working. Now I have to add another class which should listen for a queue. Hence added @JMSListener annotation which is not picking any message. Any insight will be really helpful.

The pom has below specified dependencies.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.ibm.mq</groupId>
    <artifactId>mq-jms-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.ibm.mq</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.ibm.mq.allclient</artifactId>
    <version>9.1.4.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

The class has below specified method.

```
import org.springframework.jms.annotation.JmsListener;
@Component
public class PickMyMessage {
    @JmsListener(destination = "IN",containerFactory = "myFactory")
    public void pullMyMessaage(String message){
        System.out.println("Message is pulled..");
    }
}
```

My main application has @EnableJMS annotation. In my application.yml file I have given below information.

```
ibm:
  mq:
    channel: MY.APP.SVRCONN
    connName: 192.168.0.1(1415)
    password: Pswd
    queueManager: QM01
    user: appsrv
```

My Bean class configs are

My JMS connection factory as below.

```
@Bean
    public JmsListenerContainerFactory<?> myFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
                                                    DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer) {
        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
        configurer.configure(factory, connectionFactory);
    }
```

Not sure what else I am missing here. Any insight will be really helpful.

Instead of my existing project, if i create any simple demo project it is working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

The class `PickMyMessage` is not a Spring bean, that's why Spring ignores it. Declare it as a `@Bean` or as a `@Component`.

May be there are further problems. But this is the first one that needs to be resolved.

Comment: Tried adding Component or Componentscan as like my other classes. still same issue.

Comment: OK. Now show how you connected this listener to the connection manager. Show how looks your connection factory bean.

Comment: Updated with my bean config details. I dont have connection manager in my classes. I believe it is taking default one.